# why ember-data embedded association always send an ajax request?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use Ember-Data and the provided RESTAdapter to load an object like this :

```
{
  "videos":[
   {
    "id":"5062f3c30959c6c732000005",
    "tags":[
          {"_id":"5062f3cb0959c6c732000006","name":"hello"},
          {"_id":"5062f3cb0959c6c732000007","name":" world"}
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Here I have a video object that has many tags. The `tags` attribute is declared as embedded :

```
Video = DS.Model.extend {
 tags: DS.hasMany('Tag', {embedded: true})
}

Tag = DS.Model.extend {
 video: DS.belongsTo('Video')
}
```

When I try to load video with

```
Video.find()
```

The adpter always try to send a get request to my server at `/tags` which naturally fails because my server doesn't give acces to tags directly. Instead, tags are already embedded in the /videos.json.

So what is the meaning of `embedded: true` in ember-data association ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe vaguely what's happening is that it doesn't trust the embedded `tags` without `id` parameters. Try giving `Tag` an `id: DS.attr('string', { key: '_id' })`.

By the way, `embedded` is misspelled in your example -- is it correct in your app?

**UPDATE:** Perhaps better advice would be to set `primaryKey: '_id'` inside `Tag`. ([doc](https://github.com/emberjs/data#defining-models))

Comment: +1 this is most likely the issue OP is running into, the only caution is that this is changing in the 1.0 release... 
See the Mapping section of the relationship-improvements branch:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/relationship-improvements/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#mapping

Comment: in fact, the problem is due to "_id"

Comment: Fixed the misspelling in the question.